# SQL query to display quantity

Tags: sql

I have two columns in table:

```
Item name    quantity
---------------------
A               5
```

Want to display this like:

```
Item name    quantity
---------------------
A               1
A               1
A               1
A               1
A               1
```

Comment: Please post the RDBMS and version you are using

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: what is the logic for each row? If you have quantity 10, then you need  `A  1` 10 times?

Comment: Its rqeuirement dear

Answer (score 4):

Let me assume you have a numbers table that has a single column which is an integer (one can easily be generated in most databases):

```
select t.item_name, 1 as quantity
from t join
     numbers n
     on t.quantity <= n.n;
```

For example:

```
select t.item_name, 1 as quantity
from t join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n
     on t.quantity <= n.n;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Oracle, try this:

```
SELECT i_name, 1 FROM 
  (SELECT 'A' i_name, 5 qty FROM dual) 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= qty;
```